# What is the data structure of Pybrain's network architecture?

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

Suppose we have built a feed forward network using Pybrain's `SupervisedDataSet` and `buildNetwork` functions. The architecture could be 10, 5, 2: 10 input nodes, 5 hidden nodes in a single hidden layer, and 2 output nodes.

```
>>> our_network = buildNetwork(10,5,2)
>>> for mod in our_network.modules:
...    for conn in our_network.connections[mod]:
...        conn.params

array([-0.82432749, -1.77414037, ... ,  1.96635753])
```

When examining a trained network with the above architecture, how may we interpret the output array `conn.params`? Examining the output of the above architecture will yield 50 connections/weights between the input and hidden layer. I'm interested in knowing which inputs are associated with the strongest connections. Specifically, is it safe to assume the first 5 array elements returned are associated with the connections between the first node at the input layer and the 5 hidden layer nodes?

I'm not gaining any insight via reverse engineering Pybrain for the past hour.

Answer (score 1):

Modules and connections are sorted in a unique way (evaluation order, with tie-breaking alphabetically, have a look at [sortModules()](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/structure/networks/network.py#L216)). The global *.params* array is then just the concatenation of the (flattened) parameters of all those components.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150772/pybrain-how-to-print-a-network-nodes-and-weights).