# PyBrain neuron manipulation

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

Is there a good way to add/remove a neuron and its associated connections into/from a fully connected PyBrain network? Say I start with:

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
net = buildNetwork(2,3,1)
```

How would I go about making it a (2,4,1) or a (2,2,1) network WHILE maintaining all the old weights (and initializing any new ones to be random as is done when initializing the network)? The reason I want to do this is because I am attempting to use an evolutionary learning strategy to determine the best architecture and the 'mutation' step involves adding/removing nodes with some probability. (The input and output modules should always remain the same.)

edit: I found NeuronDecomposableNetwork which should make this easier, but it still seems that I have to keep track of neurons and connections separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're doing along the lines of the [NEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeuroEvolution_of_Augmented_Topologies) algorithm?
There are two different answers to your question:

1. **Open ended** evolution of the network topology: in this case, I recommend encapsulating every neuron in its own "layer"/module, and add/remove them and their connections to the network iteratively, a bit like in [this tutorial](http://www.pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/netmodcon.html#feed-forward-networks), except that there will be many more (single-neuron) layers. Don't forget to call the `sortModules()` method after each topological change.
2. Finding the best topology within a predefined framework (say a maximum of 1000 neurons). In that case it's easier and more efficient to build the full network in the beginning, and just **mask** some of the connections (e.g. using the [`MaskedParameters`](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/structure/evolvables/maskedparameters.py) module). Among others, [memetic algorithms](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/pybrain/optimization/memetic/memetic.py) [(used like this)](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/docs/tutorials/blackboxoptimization.py#L79) are designed to search such topology spaces.

An alternative, as you say, is manually managing all the weights (by tracking [what is where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150772/pybrain-how-to-print-a-network-nodes-and-weights/8161274#8161274), or using `NeuronDecomposableNetwork`) but I *don't recommend* that.

---

A general comment: for more advanced uses of pybrain such as yours, relying on the `buildNetwork' shortcut is really too limited, and you will want to use the Network/Module/Connection API directly.

Comment: Awesome, this helps me out a ton, thanks! I really like the first idea. Never would have thought about using layers as individual neurons. And yes after trying for about three days now I would not recommend manual management either lol (the other stackoverflow post was actually where I got the idea). I'll come back after some experimenting (and researching NEAT as this is the first I've found out about it, yet being almost exactly what I wanted to get to) and update my post with the results.