# how to plot byprain neural network structure

Tags: python, pybrain

I am using pybrain to build neural network. 
Sometimes a graphical representation of the situation would be very useful.

Is it possible to plot the structure of a neural network generated using pybrain?

Comment: look "[how to print a network (nodes and weights)][1]"



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150772/pybrain-how-to-print-a-network-nodes-and-weights

Comment: Thanks but it prints the results. I am more interested in a plot

Answer (score 1):

I think the original questioner was probably looking for something like this (as I am, though without the animation): http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/predictor/learn.gif

And I think this is more or less answered in this post:
[How to visualize a neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888233/how-to-visualize-a-neural-network/31559494#31559494)

"More or less" because it would be nice to see the cell reference (A0, A1, A2, B0, etc, or whatever) inside each circle.

But I'm a total beginner in Python and in neural networks, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

- Guy

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned, this answer [How to visualize a neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888233/how-to-visualize-a-neural-network/31559494#31559494) shows how to plot simple networks using pyplot.

Here is how to adapt this solution for PyBrain:

```
class PybrainNNVisualizer():
    def __init__(self, neural_network):
        """
        :type neural_network: Network
        """
        self.neural_network = neural_network

    def draw(self):
        widest_layer = max([layer.dim for layer in self.neural_network.modules])
        network = NeuralNetwork(widest_layer)
        for layer in self.neural_network.modulesSorted:
            if type(layer) is BiasUnit:
                continue
            network.add_layer(layer.dim)
        network.draw()
```

Usage:

```
fnn = buildNetwork(4, 8, 1)

PybrainNNVisualizer(fnn).draw()
```

Full source code: https://github.com/AlexP11223/SimplePyBrainNeuralNeutwork/blob/master/nnvisualizer.py